# Can I call pushd/popd and prevent it printing the stack?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, command-line-interface, shell

After calling `pushd`/`popd` in bash, it will print off the current directory stack. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour, so that it will act 'quitely'? This sort of noise in a command is uncommon in unix tools.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think this sort of "noise" is **not** uncommon, that's why you often do this:

```
pushd > /dev/null
```

Comment: You can also make a function to basically redefine the command and stick it in `.bashrc` such as:
`pushd() { builtin pushd $1 > /dev/null; }`

Comment: @jrod: Since `pushd` can takes multiple arguments, you might want that as `pushd() { builtin pushd "$@" > /dev/null; }` and the quotes handle directory names with spaces.

Comment: Good tip, but most unix tools don't print to the terminal EVERY TIME, but only if there's an error

Comment: I'd say its uncommon. The linux philosophy is actually to not print anything if everything went well except the output of the program or builtin if any. For example cd, ls, aso.

Comment: Some people do `pushd &> /dev/null`. I'd say don't do that because `&` means redirect *both* stdout and stderr. Normally you only want to redirect stdout.

Comment: `popd` also generates console output, so consider silencing it in the same way

Answer (score -1):

For the tcsh shell you can: 
    set pushdsilent